# Why is bot undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am developing a Discord bot using the Discord.js API. So far so good, but I thought it would be nice to have the newest post on a relevant subreddit be announced in the chat by my bot every couple of minutes. Now I have managed to make the script pull the relevant data out of the Reddit JSON API, but this error is thrown:

> ```js
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendMessage' of undefined
>     at /data/app/app.js:810:7
>     at Array.forEach (native)
>     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/data/app/app.js:808:36)
>     at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
>     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
>     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
>     at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
>     at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
> /data/app/app.js:810
>         bot.sendMessage(channel,"https://www.reddit.com" + child.data.permalink);
> ```

This is my code:

```js
var Discord = require("discord.js");
var bot = new Discord.Client();


var redditSubModule = "pics";

function getRedditPosts(bot, msg) {
  var url = "http://www.reddit.com/r/" + redditSubModule + "/new/.json?limit=2";
  var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
    var json = "";
    response.on("data", function(chunk) {
      json += chunk;
    });

    response.on("end", function() {
      var redditResponse = JSON.parse(json);
      redditResponse.data.children.forEach(function(child) {
        console.log("https://www.reddit.com" + child.data.permalink);
        bot.sendMessage(msg.channel,"https://www.reddit.com" + child.data.permalink);
      });
    });
  });

  request.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

  setTimeout(getRedditPosts, 60000);
}

getRedditPosts();
```

Why is `bot` undefined?

Comment: The parameter `bot` in `getRedditPosts` creates a new local variable `bot`, which prevents you from using closure to access the `bot` variable you defined globally. You are calling `getRedditPosts` without any arguments, so both parameters, `bot` and `msg`, are `undefined`. Likewise the call to `getRedditPosts` that the timeout makes will have no arguments either.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're expecting `getRedditPosts` to be called with attributes `(bot, msg)`, but you are calling it with no attributes `getRedditPosts();`

So basically you are passing `undefined` as the `bot` variable.
`undefined` has no functions on it and you are trying to call `sendMessage`

and that is the meaning of `Cannot read property 'sendMessage' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to call the function getRedditPosts() when a user runs a command. Something like:

```
bot.on('message', (msg)=>{
 if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("!redditcommand")) {
  getRedditPosts(msg.client, msg)
 }
}
```

At the end of your code in place of the getRedditPosts(); should do the trick.